# Multi-threaded Scientific data visualization in c++

Tags: data-visualization

I have a process which generates a data vector from a sensor.I'm using Intel Integrated Performance Primitives v5.3 update 3 for Windows on IA-32 to process it further for some calculations.I want to know if there is any c++ library which allows to plot the vector as a histogram/bar chart during data acquisition.I can write the multi-threaded code,but need information on availability of plotting functions in C++.  This thing is pretty simple in MATLAB ,but I want to do it using c++ .

Suggestions are welcome !!

Answer (score 6):

You can try one of these:

- [CBarChart](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/CBarChart.aspx)
- [Scientific charting control](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/xgraph.aspx)
- [High-speed Charting Control](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/High-speedCharting.aspx)
- [VTK](http://www.vtk.org/)
- [ChartDirector](http://www.advsofteng.com/)
- [Charting Library](http://www.gigasoft.com/)
- [GDCHART](http://www.fred.net/brv/chart/)
- [Carnac Chart Library](http://www.int.com/products/2d/carnac/chart_component.htm)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above, VTK is an open source C++ viz library. And more importantly, it is by-design parallelized. It will try and use whatever hardware you can give it.

Answer (score 0):

I use OpenInventor for scientific visualisation.  It may be (in some ways) a relic of the old SGI days, but it is still being supported and works well.  Regarding graphing and other scientific visualisation, look at MeshViz and other extensions from Mercury:

- [Mercury (formerly TGS) OpenInventor](http://www.tgs.com/) or [Coin](http://www.coin3d.org/), a dual-licensed (GPL + commercial) alternative
- [MeshViz extension](http://www.tgs.com/products/oiv_mesh_viz_overview.asp)

It has charting, vector visualisation, etc.  It's quite comprehensive.

It's not free, but they do trial licenses so you can determine if it suits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

[MathGL](http://mathgl.sourceforge.net/) plotting functions can be executed in separate thread and can be parallelized by user-side.